# How to add a row in CSV file using shiny and save it?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am new to R programming, I was using Shiny to enter the CSV file where user can add a new row in the CSV file and can save that file
Till now I made a shiny app to ask the user to upload a CSV file and display the data, but don't know how to add a new row so that the user can add details and upload it in the same CSV file?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("ADD YOUR DATA"), sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("This app shows how a user can upload a csv file.
          if the data is in same format as the sample file, downloadable below
          "),
            
            tags$hr(),
            fileInput("file","Upload the file"), 
            textInput("quantity", "Quantity"),
            textInput("date", "Date"),
            h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
            checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = TRUE),
            checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
            br(),
            radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
            tableOutput("file"),
            actionButton("Action", "Submit"),
            downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("tb"),
            
        )
    )
)


library(shiny)


server <- function(input,output){
    data <- reactive({
        
        
        file1 <- input$file
        if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
        
        read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)})
    
    output$filedf <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(data())){return ()}
        input$file
    }) 
    
    output$sum <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(data())){return ()}
        summary(data())
    })
    
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(data())){return ()}
        data()
    })
    
     output$tb <- renderUI({if(is.null(data()))
        h5()               
        else
            tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
    
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```